# Get the last inserted record's primary key

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have Entity class named Driver, My primary key generation mechanism is

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long id;
```

Now I need to add "driverCode" attribute to the Driver, It should be unique value with prefix (dri1, dri2), "dri" is the prefix value , key should be the primary key value of the Driver, I want to add the driverCode when the driver is created at first time, To do that I need to get the last inserted Driver's primary key, add one ,and concatenate with the prefix, Can any one tell how to get the last inserted record's primary key before insert a new record, Is there any easy way to this?,

Thank you in advance,

Comment: not being a java programmer, I don't know if the java libs have a built in function/method for this, but you can always simply run a `select last_insert_id()` query to get that ID.

Comment: Consider removing irrelevant text from your question - approximately 90% of the text in your question has nothing to do with the actual question, which is simply "How do I find the last inserted id value"

Comment: Bohemian, I'll do it in next time when I post , I want to tell my exact requirement, sorry about that, thank you pointing out that

Comment: Marc B, I tried "select last_insert_id()", It returns "0", It doesn't give what I want, any other way I can use for this?,

Answer (score 8):

If you [`flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush%28%29) your `EntityManger`, the `@Id` field will be populated with the value about to be 
saved to the database, so you don't need to find the last one inserted because you already know the current one being inserted:

```
EntityManger em;
Driver d = new Driver();
em.persist(d);
em.flush();
long id = d.getId(); // this will give you the current record's id
```

Also, it is quite tricky, and dangerous, to "get the last inserted id"; it is nowhere near as simple as it seems.

Comment: Part of the trickiness that Bohemian refers to is that some other thread could insert another record between your code persisting a record and trying to find what the last id inserted is.  So even if you can get an answer, you can't be sure it is right ... for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response,This happens only if I inserted a next record at the same time, Am I right? , Is there any other way to add unique sequence to the driverCode?

Comment: Stephen C, Thank you for the response, Any other way that I can use to generate unique no?

Answer (score 4):

the one that works for me

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

then you can

```
object.getId();
```